# how to mock new SimpleJdbcCall

Tags: java, junit, powermockito

Can you please help me to mock SimpleJdbcCall?

the actual class to test is below.

```
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class HeartBeat {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(HeartBeat.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

    
    @PostConstruct
    private void applicationStarted() {
        LOGGER.info("Application has Started.");
        DBCall();
    }
    
    @Scheduled(fixedRateString="${application.heartbeatInterval}")
    public void sendHeartbeat() {
        DBCall();
    }
    
    private void DBCall() {

        if ( this.jdbcTemplate == null ) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
        
        jdbcTemplate.setResultsMapCaseInsensitive(true);

        jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withSchemaName("schema")
            .withCatalogName("catalogName")
            .withProcedureName("cleanup");

        jdbcCall.execute(new HashMap<String, Object>(0));
        
        jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
            .withSchemaName("schema")
            .withCatalogName("catalogName")
            .withProcedureName("register")
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("id", Types.VARCHAR))
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("name", Types.VARCHAR));
        MapSqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", "abc").addValue("name", "def");
        
        jdbcCall.execute(paramMap);

    }
}
```

to test out above code, I've created

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyMap;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HeartBeatTest {
    HeartBeat heartBeat;

    private JdbcTemplate mockedJdbcTemplate;
    private SimpleJdbcCall mockedJdbcCall;
    private Map<String, Object> result;
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.heartBeatComponent = new HeartBeatComponent();
        result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        mockedJdbcTemplate = Mockito.mock(JdbcTemplate.class);
        mockedJdbcCall = Mockito.mock(SimpleJdbcCall.class);
    
        Whitebox.setInternalState(heartBeatComponent, "jdbcTemplate",mockedJdbcTemplate);
        Whitebox.setInternalState(heartBeatComponent, "jdbcCall",mockedJdbcCall);
        
        // section1
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(SimpleJdbcCall.class).withArguments(mockedJdbcTemplate).thenReturn(mockedJdbcCall);

        // section2
        PowerMockito.whenNew(SimpleJdbcCall.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockedJdbcCall);
        Mockito.when(mockedJdbcCall.withSchemaName(any(String.class))).thenReturn(mockedJdbcCall);
        Mockito.when(mockedJdbcCall.withCatalogName(any(String.class))).thenReturn(mockedJdbcCall);
        Mockito.when(mockedJdbcCall.withProcedureName(any(String.class))).thenReturn(mockedJdbcCall);

    }
    
    @Test
    public void sendHeartbeatTest() {
        Mockito.when(mockedJdbcCall.execute(anyMap())).thenReturn(result);
        Mockito.when(mockedJdbcCall.execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class))).thenReturn(result);
        
        heartBeat.sendHeartbeat();
        
        Mockito.verify(mockedJdbcCall, Mockito.times(1)).execute(anyMap());
        Mockito.verify(mockedJdbcCall, Mockito.times(1)).execute(any(MapSqlParameterSource.class));
        
    }
    
}
```

but it does not work as expected. what I can see from debug mode,
jdbcCall got mockedJdbcCall but because of new SimpleJdbcCall() along with .withSchemaName and others, it got overwritten by simpleJdbcCall. My expectation was when new SimpleJdbcCall being called it returns mockedJdbcCall that I set up PowerMockito.whenNew...

I've tried section 1 and section 2 for PowerMockito.whenNew
Did I misunderstand PowerMockito.whenNew? or missed anything from the code?

Please, guide me.

Comment: For what it's worth I don't recommend mocking JDBC.  Unit tests with mocked-out JDBC dependencies would never test anything such as whether the stored procedure exists, has the expected number and types of parameters, the user you are connected as has permission to execute it, and various other database-specific problems.  Personally, I feel it's better to have integration tests that connect to a real database instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell PowerMock that you want to mock construction of the `SimpleJdbcCall` class inside the `HeartBeat` class. Try adding the following annotations to your test class:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(HeartBeat.class)
public class HeartBeatTest {
  ...
}
```

Reference: [how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#how-to-mock-construction-of-new-objects)